# Mac Id is coming same in 2 PCs while using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, mac-address

I have developed a software in C#, in which registration is done using mac id of PC as unique identifier. I registered the software on one PC using internet via usb tethering of my mobile, it took a mac id and got registered successfully. But when I tried to register on another PC using my mobile's internet via usb tethering, it is showing the same mac id which I got on registering first PC. I checked mac id of both PCs using ipconfig/all command in cmd and there same id is shown under physical address when my mobile is connected for internet. Why is this happening? What is the solution for this?

Code I used to fetch mac id:

```
string macAddresses = "", FinalmacAddresses = "";

foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    macAddresses = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
    break;
}

    FinalmacAddresses = macAddresses.Trim().ToString();
    return FinalmacAddresses;
```

Comment: Arent you getting the mac of your mobile?

Comment: Do either of these PC's have a network card or a wifi card? if not then guess what - they don't even have a mac address.

Comment: Solution: use something other than the mac address as unique identifier for a pc.

Comment: @AsheraH What should I use instead of mac address?

Comment: @KshitijMatey cause [Mac Addresses are not unique](http://superuser.com/questions/968340/how-is-uniqueness-of-mac-addresses-enforced)!

Comment: We might be able to give a better suggestion if you explain what you mean by “registration”.

Comment: @DourHighArch Here "registration" means software registration for a single PC like we do Antivirus software registration, for Activation purpose. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you should never use a mac address as a unique identifier. There are tools and even simple ways by which you can assign multiple devices with the same mac address (Mac address spoofing). That is also not good, if we look through the security perspective.

I would recommend using a GUID instead.

Comment: Is there any chances of matching GUID for 2 different PCs?

Comment: In future, if PC is formatted and we reinstall the software then how will I check if the user is already registered? Is it possible using GUID? and How?

Comment: What if they change the hard drive - is that a new PC? What about the motherboard and the monitor? The only way to link a licence like that is to link it to person through an email, or get them to generate a code and have you store it in a database somewhere. Just remember though... software is virtually free nowadays. It'll have to be an awesome product for anyone to go through any kind of licencing rigmarole.